# How to make a call to an executable from Python script?

Tags: python, linux, executable, system-calls

I need to execute this script from my Python script.

Is it possible? The script generate some outputs with some files being written. How do I access these files? I have tried with subprocess call function but without success.

```
fx@fx-ubuntu:~/Documents/projects/foo$ bin/bar -c somefile.xml -d text.txt -r aString -f anotherString >output
```

The application "bar" also references to some libraries, it also create the file "bar.xml" besides the output. How do I get access to these files? Just by using open()?

Thank you,

**Edit:**

The error from Python runtime is only this line.

```
$ python foo.py
bin/bar: bin/bar: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: subprocess is what you need to use, can you provide an example so we have a better idea why it didn't work?

Comment: "subprocess call"?  What is that?  Please post the code you used and the error you actually got.

Comment: Yes, he's talking about the "call" function in the standard "subprocess" module, which is the better way to do this, although os.system may be adequate depending on his needs

Comment: Hi Kaleb, I edited the question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For executing the external program, do this:

```
import subprocess
args = ("bin/bar", "-c", "somefile.xml", "-d", "text.txt", "-r", "aString", "-f", "anotherString")
#Or just:
#args = "bin/bar -c somefile.xml -d text.txt -r aString -f anotherString".split()
popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.wait()
output = popen.stdout.read()
print output
```

And yes, assuming your `bin/bar` program wrote some other assorted files to disk, you can open them as normal with `open("path/to/output/file.txt")`. Note that you don't need to rely on a subshell to redirect the output to a file on disk named "output" if you don't want to.  I'm showing here how to directly read the output into your python program without going to disk in between.

Comment: Hi Peter, there is the error: bin/bar: bin/bar: cannot execute binary file and without any other information from the Python runtime. What is the cause?

Comment: it's about the executable's error. I have solved it, thanks Peter.

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way is:

```
import os
cmd = 'bin/bar --option --otheroption'
os.system(cmd) # returns the exit status
```

You access the files in the usual way, by using `open()`.

If you need to do more complicated subprocess management then the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is the way to go.

Comment: Note that this has the same security caveat as `subprocess.Popen(shell=True)`. Don't use it with anything other than a literal string.

Comment: I want to execute `tesseract` on every file in my folder, so I os.walk and then do the progr in the loop. How does it work?

Answer (score 9):

For executing a unix executable file. I did the following in my Mac OSX and it worked for me:

```
import os
cmd = './darknet-classifier-predict-data/baby.jpg'
so = os.popen(cmd).read()
print(so)
```

Here `print(so)` outputs the result.