# Running a C executable from Python with command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line, executable

I have a C file say, `myfile.c`.

Now to compile I am doing : `gcc myfile.c -o myfile`

So now to run this I need to do : `./myfile inputFileName > outputFileName`

Where `inputFileName` and `outputFileName` are 2 command line inputs.

Now I am trying to execute this within a python program and I am trying this below approach but it is not working properly may be due to the `>`

```
import subprocess
import sys

inputFileName = sys.argv[1];
outputFileName = sys.argv[2];

subprocess.run(['/home/dev/Desktop/myfile', inputFileName, outputFileName])
```

Where `/home/dev/Desktop` is the name of my directory and `myfile` is the name of the executable file.

What should I do?

Comment: You should be a able to directly run the C file from python as a module. Please take a [look at this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762621/can-we-use-c-code-in-python) question which can lead to this [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/index.html.).

Comment: Is the author perhaps missing the '>' in their subprocess command?

Comment: `> outputFileName` is ouput redirection. It's something your shell is doing - it's not an argument to your program. To reproduce that with python, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a call to an executable from Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473655/how-to-make-a-call-to-an-executable-from-python-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` that you use in your command is a shell-specific syntax for [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). If you want to do the same through Python, you will have to invoke the shell to do it for you, with `shell=True` and with a single command line (not a list).

Like this:

```py
subprocess.run(f'/home/dev/Desktop/myfile "{inputFileName}" > "{outputFileName}"', shell=True)
```

If you want to do this through Python only without invoking the shell (which is what `shell=True` does) take a look at this other Q&A: [How to redirect output with subprocess in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the output file in Python, and pass the file object to `subprocess.run()`.

```
import subprocess
import sys

inputFileName = sys.argv[1];
outputFileName = sys.argv[2];

with open(outputFileName, "w") as out:
    subprocess.run(['/home/dev/Desktop/myfile', inputFileName], stdout=out)
```